# При клике на одну кнопку dropdown-menu открываются все меню

Tags: html, bootstrap

Есть страница на которой n-е количество кнопок при клике на которые должен открываться блок текста. Я реализовал это с помощью dropdown в bootstrap-е.
Но возникла проблема - при клике на одну из кнопок выплывают все блоки текста во всех меню. Как это исправить?

```
<button type="button" class="btn-links btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><h5>Title 1<span><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span></h5>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu links-menu">
        <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, optio.</p></li>

      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="btn-links btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><h5>Title 2<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span></h5>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu links-menu">
        <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Omnis, optio.</p></li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ. Вместо dropdown использовать collapse